Keep Google logo image inside Elevated Button
I am trying to add the Google logo inside my Elevatedbutton. I tried searching but can't find anything useful. I found only adding icons via ElevatedButton.icon. How can I show Google or Facebook or any other logos inside my elevated button.

You might want to check out the specific brand guidelines before "altering" logo's (and google's brand guideline)

you can use this package to get the all brand as icon
for Example you can use this in icon:
   Brand(Brands.facebook),
   Brand(Brands.google),
   Brand(Brands.android_studio),

all this return the logo as icon

     Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Brand(Brands.google)),
          IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Brand(Brands.facebook)),
          IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Brand(Brands.stack_overflow)),
        ],
      ),
     const SizedBox(height: 20),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {},
            label: Brand(Brands.google),
          ),
          ElevatedButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {},
            label: Brand(Brands.facebook),
          ),
          ElevatedButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {},
            label: Brand(Brands.stack_overflow),
          ),
        ],
      ),

this is how to use it

i will add in other answer with the result for code now

im editig now , i forgit this option
